# Cant drag back product Attribute to unassigned attribute in Magento 2.2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, attributes, product-attribute, attribute-set

Cant drag back product Attribute to unassigned attribute in Magento 2.2

I am not removing a default attribute, its created by me Manufacturer.

[image]

Comment: You need to drag to empty folder option showing at the top. Drag and drop on the empty folder icon.

Comment: Thank You, Its working. Hope Magneto updated it in future version.

Comment: No, If you know you can that will help others.  I will try with any new release if its changed.

Comment: Move it between the other two unassigned attributes

Answer (score 0):

Can't drag ( empty folder option is not visible  in Unassigned Attributes)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

2 Options that I found how unassigned the attributes:

1. Create a new Group by "Add New" button and call it Empty, drag from left to right the attribute, to inside to folder that created "Empty"
2. Delete Selected Group - move all the attributes that you like to unassigned under the same folder, select it and click "Delete Selected Group" 
   you can do that only for standard attributes,  not system attributes

On Magento 2.3.3V